# Showing that the expected trajectory of a supermartingale is Càdlàg.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, continuity

I have a stochastic process $X_t$, on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$, adapted to the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$. It is a super-martingale, hence if $s \le t$: $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]\le X_s$.

I want to prove that $t: \rightarrow E(X_t)$ is a Càdlàg-trajectory.

What I have managed to do is this: If $s\le t$, then $E[X_t]=E[E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]]$ by law of total expectation. And then $E[E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]]\le E[X_s]$. Using this and the fundamental theorem of analysis, we see that at every point the trajectory has a left and right limit.

But I need to prove that the limit from the right is the same as the desired function value. That is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[X_{t+1/n}]=L=E[X_t]$. What I obviously have from above is that $L\le E[X_t]$, But I do not see how to exclude the possibility that it is strictly less than $E[X_t]$. Do you see how to do this?

PS: I have not seen this property stated anywhere. But the reason I am wondering is that this is a property that is used in a theorem, and I heard that the theorem works for supermartingales, and so, this property should hold for supermartingales. But since I have this from two different sources I am not entirely sure that the property holds, so if you think it does not hold, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true. Consider, for example, a stopping time $T$ of your filtration, and define $X_t=1_{\{t\le T\}}$. This is a non-increasing, adapted, non-negative process, hence a supermartingale. Also, $E[X_t]=P[t\le T]$ is left continuous, and will have a jump discontinuity at any $t$ with $P[T=t]>0$. Your conclusion that $L\le E[X_t]$ is the best that can be said in general.